# how to write Rails 4 scope for SQL statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

Currently I am upgrading my application to rails 4.i know there are some syntax changes made for writing scopes in rails4 for SQL statement.
below is the scope in rails 3:

```
scope :current_active_leases,     group("leases.id").where("leases.commencement <= ? and (leases.expiration >= ? or leases.mtm=?) and leases.is_executed= ? ", Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), true, true)
```

how to rewrite this in rails 4

Comment: You have error in your scope. It should be placed in lambda - otherwise your dates are evaluated once, at class code execution. This addresses to Rails 3 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what ever you have written should work but in rails 4 you should write like

```
scope :current_active_leases,  -> {group("leases.id").where("leases.commencement <= ? and (leases.expiration >= ? or leases.mtm=?) and leases.is_executed= ? ", Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), true, true) }
```

Check the documentation
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope